# Screenshots taken with Python are totally black

Tags: python, win32gui

So I have this code:

```
import win32gui
import win32ui
from ctypes import windll
from PIL import Image

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, "#chat - Discord")

# Change the line below depending on whether you want the whole window
# or just the client area. 
left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetClientRect(hwnd)
#left, top, right, bot = win32gui.GetWindowRect(hwnd)
w = right - left
h = bot - top

hwndDC = win32gui.GetWindowDC(hwnd)
mfcDC  = win32ui.CreateDCFromHandle(hwndDC)
saveDC = mfcDC.CreateCompatibleDC()

saveBitMap = win32ui.CreateBitmap()
saveBitMap.CreateCompatibleBitmap(mfcDC, w, h)

saveDC.SelectObject(saveBitMap)

# Change the line below depending on whether you want the whole window
# or just the client area. 
result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 1)
#result = windll.user32.PrintWindow(hwnd, saveDC.GetSafeHdc(), 0)


bmpinfo = saveBitMap.GetInfo()
bmpstr = saveBitMap.GetBitmapBits(True)

im = Image.frombuffer(
    'RGB',
    (bmpinfo['bmWidth'], bmpinfo['bmHeight']),
    bmpstr, 'raw', 'BGRX', 0, 1)

if result:
    #PrintWindow Succeeded
    im.show()

win32gui.DeleteObject(saveBitMap.GetHandle())
saveDC.DeleteDC()
mfcDC.DeleteDC()
win32gui.ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwndDC)
```

The problem with it is that the screenshot it takes is all black. It does this with all windows, not just Discord. What is wrong with it, and what do I need to do to fix it?

Also as a side question - when I take screenshots the command prompt opens and then close real quick, is there also a way to stop that from happening?

Comment: This is probably unhelpful, but in your `Image.frombuffer` call, I think 'BGRX' should be 'RGBX'.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with it is that the screenshot it takes is all black.

I understand that you want to take a screenshot?

```
from PIL.ImageGrab import grab
image = grab()
image.save('Screenshot.png')
```

If you have the coordinates of the window, try this instead:

```
from PIL.ImageGrab import grab
box = (0,0,200,200)
image = grab(box)
image.save('Screenshot.png')
```

PIL has been discontinued though, so you may be able to use this code only for the next immediate future. Also, the command prompt does not appear with this code.